# What does sts means in CSS?

Tags: css, styling

Can't understand what **sts** means here,
`display: block;sts`
anyone can help?

[**with sts**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvOnO.png)

[**without sts**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak5Yd.png)

Comment: `sts` is nothing. Its wrong CSS that you have written. After, semi-colon, your CSS property and value is completed. Its just typo. You just made a typo, so whatever CSS you wrote after that, is invalidated, till it meets another `;` (semi-colon), after that whatever you write again, will be applied - as valid CSS.

Comment: oh, okay thank youu

Answer (score 3):

This is nothing meaningful in css. But since it has no semicolon, it has made the next line not work. So the text is not uppercase.

Comment: okay, thanks a lot.